# Read Maven SCM url value from Properties file

Tags: java, maven, svn

My pom.xml has scm configuration as follows

```
<scm>
 <url>${my.scm.url}</url>
</scm>
```

I have property file which I am reading using properties-maven-plugin which has the value of ${my.scm.url}, and also I am using buildnumber-maven-plugin to get latest revision from SVN.

The issue is buildnumber-maven-plugin throws invalid scm url error but, when i replace ${my.scm.url} with actual url to my svn repo , it works perfectly.

How can I achieve successful execution without having to hard code scm url ?

PS: I run build using : `mvn clean install command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably due to the order that the plugins run. The following should work:

1. Bind the `properties-maven-plugin` to the `initialize` phase
2. **AFTER** that plugin configuration in the POM, add the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` plugin
3. **AFTER** the previous two, put the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` plugin (which by default bind to the `initialize` phase).

Now all 3 plugins should run in the correct order (you can check this from the logs). Alternatively you can bind the to different phases to ensure that they run in the correct order, but the above should be enough and conforms with the goal of the [`initialize` phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) (*initialize build state, e.g. set properties or create directories*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer , what is the difference between point 2 and 3.Can you elaborate.

Comment: Your answer however has nudged me in the right direction and I got it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't post the POM file, I'm guessing a bit.

Obviously, the order is going to matter, you must get the properties loaded first.  That said, looking at the [mojo](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/), I'm not sure setting properties is the equivalent of essentially setting a -D.

If you did a mvn -Dscm.url= clean install, then the value would be there because it's being defined to the mvn JVM.  Depending at what point the ${scm.url} is being evaluated, if it's before the properties mojo has a chance to run, it's going to be too late.

If you use a CI tool (i.e. Jenkins, Hudson) that can load the properties *before* the mvn call, then the variable is defined.

I've used the buildNumber mojo for my builds, because I have buildNumbers automatically generated for my snapshot artifacts.  The order things occurred:

1. property file is downloaded from Jenkins master to slave for this job
2. Jenkins plugin loads the properties file into the job
3. maven build starts, the build number is already defined before mvn is called (again, behaving like a -D) and my buildNumber is incorporated into my artifact version
4. buildNumber mojo causes the property file to have buildNumber incremented
5. property file copied back to Jenkins master

I also wanted to load the properties file within maven and have it "update" the artifact id on the fly, but by that point, Maven had already evaluated; hence, I had to do it beforehand.

Hope this helps.